# How can I integrate LinkedIn within an iPhone application?

Tags: iphone, linkedin-api

I need your help to know regarding integrating linkedin with my iPhone Application.

I do Googling and am able to create an API for LinkedIn. Using [link](http://developer.linkedin.com/community/apis).

But since I am newbie, I stop here. I have both API Key and Secret Key, But I don't know how do I use it to make it Successful in iPhone Application.

So it's my request to you all to suggest me proper way. Maybe I will learn something new from you.

Comment: look this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=PXuu3t3pIe4

Answer (score 6):

For other folks looking for sample iPhone applications for LinkedIn, I wrote a sample client which is on GitHub (which was presented at the Silicon Valley iOS Meetup last year):

https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

Comment: Absolutely awesome! Just one question is the client code compatible with the new iOS >=6 ?

Comment: @kirsten jones  whenever am trying to build, it shows an alert, you don't have permission, what to do?

Answer (score 2):

Please try LIExplorer for iOS. It seems to be a promising library which provides LinkedIn authentication and API calls. It also manages token caching.

[https://github.com/vijayviswas/LIExplorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27182023/getting-the-difference-between-two-nsdates-in-months-days-hours-minutes-seconds)

Answer (score 0):

Download a library from : https://github.com/NasirMalik/LinkedIn-iOS-Status

In this library .c file is also used that's why use compile source as: `Objective-C` (in build settings) instead of file type.

Write this code in your click event:

```
profileTabView=[[ProfileTabView alloc] init];
profileTabView.parentVC=self;
profileTabView.view.frame=CGRectMake(0, 0, profileTabView.view.frame.size.width, profileTabView.view.frame.size.height);
[self.view addSubview:profileTabView.view];
```