# How to share text/urls on linkedin through iPhone App?

Tags: iphone, ios, share, linkedin-api

I'm working on app which needs Linkedin connectivity i.e user should be able to share some text/urls on linkedin through the app.

Any sample code would be a great help.

Many Thanks

iPhoneDeveloper

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I integrate LinkedIn within an iPhone application?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085048/how-can-i-integrate-linkedin-within-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 2):

Have you seen this:
http://www.whitneyland.com/2011/03/iphone-oauth.html

or this:

https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone

They should help you get started on iOS

Answer (score 0):

I think you can find all informations here :
https://developer.linkedin.com/apis

and here https://developer.linkedin.com/documents/linkedin-api-resource-map#

Comment: Thanks for your help Christopher, I just got to know that I have to use the following api for sharing something on linkedin:
 http://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~/shares but I am not able to find a proper way to use it, i know it does not sound good but still seeking for ur help, if you could help me more with some code of using this API, I would be really very great full to you, thanks