# How i will add Linkedin library&auth to my project?

Tags: iphone

I have an iphone application in which i want to integrate linked in login and all the features of it.Is there any tutorial or blog which explaining how to do this.Can anybody help me..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible duplicate of : [How can I integrate LinkedIn within an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085048/how-can-i-integrate-linkedin-within-an-iphone-application)

Check the second answer, and this sample project : https://github.com/synedra/LinkedIn-OAuth-Sample-Client

Hope this helps!