# Post message on "https://path.com/" and "linkedin" in Iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, linkedin-api

Can I post message from my Application on following social Sites.

1)"https://path.com/"
 2) "linkedin"

I refered this links.

http://developer.linkedin.com/thread/1169

http://service.path.com/

[How can I integrate LinkedIn within an iPhone application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2085048/how-can-i-integrate-linkedin-within-an-iphone-application)

Answer (score 3):

For Linked integration you can use [this library](https://github.com/ResultsDirect/LinkedIn-iPhone)

Comment: I think path.com is custom services and also it's API is not available i think so.